# HTML/JS code works in plain browser view, but fails to work as a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to make a simple extension that would save short pastes. I'm only at the point where putting the paste in the form would change the innerHTML of the div right below the form; however, that's not the problem I'm having.

My problem is that when I try and use the code from the Chrome Extension, it fails to change the innerHTML of the div under the form, but when I run the code plainly on the browser, the code does what I intend it to do and works just as I expected it to.

Is it a problem with my code? Is there anything extra that needs to be done with Chrome Extensions so that my JavaScript code works? Anything helps!

Thanks

Code: 
HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
        <style>
            body {
                min-width: 357px;
                overflow: hidden;
                height: 700px;
                background-color: #F7F8E0;
            }

        </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html
     -->
    <!--<script src="popup.js"></script>-->
    <script src="pastebook.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="newpaste">
            New Paste: <input type="text" name="pasteform" value="Paste your new Paste">
            <button type="button" onclick="newPaste()">Save Paste</button>
        </form>

        <div id="bookofpastes"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function newPaste() {
    newpaste=document.newpaste.pasteform.value;
    document.getElementById("bookofpastes").innerHTML=newpaste;
}
```

And if it helps, my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "pastebook",
    "description": "Keep a list of all your pastes here",
    "version": "0.1",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "book2.png",
        "default_popup": "pastebook.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I found something that may be the problem. In the JS, when I put `document.getElementById("bookofpastes").innerHTML=newpaste;
`, I think `document.` will fail to work in the chrome extension...

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't use inline javascript code with manifest version 2:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/BEAGuCsX4pU

Comment: ... and `onClick` counts as inline javascript.